# What is the "language of Canaan" in Yeshayahu 19:18?

Tags: hebrew, egypt, isaiah-yeshaya-the-book, canaan

Isaiah 19:18 says

> בַּיּ֣וֹם הַה֡וּא יִהְיוּ֩ חָמֵ֨שׁ עָרִ֜ים בְּאֶ֣רֶץ מִצְרַ֗יִם
> מְדַבְּרוֹת֙ שְׂפַ֣ת כְּנַ֔עַן

What is שְׂפַ֣ת כְּנַ֔עַן in this context? Why does Yeshayahu identify the language with *Canaan* instead of directly with Hebrew?

Answer (score 4):

In the entry "[Canaanite and Hebrew](https://referenceworks.brillonline.com/entries/encyclopedia-of-hebrew-language-and-linguistics/canaanite-and-hebrew-EHLL_COM_00000351)" in the Encyclopedia of Hebrew Language and Linguistics, we have

> In the Bible, Hebrew is once referred to as שְׂפַ֣ת כְּנַ֔עַן śəp̄at
> kənaʿan ‘the language of Canaan’ (Isa. 19.18), although the more
> commonly found term is יְהוּדִית yəhūḏīṯ ‘Judahite’ (2 Kgs 18.26, 28; 2
> Chron. 32.18; Neh. 13.24; Isa. 36.11).

We find this in the commentaries as well, e.g. Rashi

> "מדברות שפת כנען - כישראל שבארץ כנען
>
> the language of Cana'an -- As Israel, which is in the land of Canaan [speaks]

or Rav Kara:

> שפת כנען - זהו לשון הקודש.
>
> the language of Cana'an -- This is the Holy Tongue

or Ibn Ezra:

> שפת כנען - מזה נלמוד ,כי הכנענים בלשון הקודש היו מדברים.
>
> the language of Cana'an -- From this we learn that the Canaanites used to speak the Holy Tongue

Comment: Great answer! What would make it a better answer is if it were to tackle the second half as well: "*Why* does Yeshayahu identify the language with Canaan instead of directly with Hebrew?"

Comment: @Deuteronomy Look at [Radak's commentary](https://www.mgketer.org/tanach/12/19/18) on the verse

Comment: If you understand the Radaq to answer the question, I suggest editing it in and explaining how :)

Answer (score 0):

Hebrew was indigenous to Canaan even prior to Avraham arriving there (whose native language was Aramaic) and is therefore associated with Canaan. See Ramban to [Bereishis 45:12](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Ramban/Bereshit/45.12#m6e1n6)